# Changing JWPlayer video on Click

Tags: javascript, onclick, jwplayer

I read this [Changing JWPlayer video onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024840/changing-jwplayer-video-onclick) and tried it but i am having problems playing the second video. Whenever i click on "Play Video 2" nothing happens! Code Below

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>My JWPlayer</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js" ></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     function changeVideo(filename) {
     jwplayer("video").setup({
       file: filename,",
        height: 360,
        width: 640,
    });
    jwplayer('video').load();
}
     </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="video">Loading the player ...</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("video").setup({
            file: "http://longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.flv",
            height: 360,
            width: 640
        });
    </script>

       <p><a href="javascript:void();" onclick="javascript:changeVideo("http://www.auby.no/files/video_tests/h264_720p_mp_3.1_3mbps_aac_shrinkage.mp4");">Play Video 2</a></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: change your onclick attribute to : onclick="javascript:changeVideo('urlString');"

Comment: Also, put up a link if possible?

Comment: You have syntax errors in the changeVideo function definition. Remove the comma after "width: 640". And 'file: filename,",' should be "file: filename,"

Comment: still no luck, here is a link to it: http://wetesting.vacau.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeVideo(filename) {
    jwplayer("video")
        .setup({
            file: filename,
            height: 360,
            width: 640
        })
        .load()
    ;
}

changeVideo("videoURL01");

$(".changeVideo").click(function()
{
  var videoUrl = $(this).attr("data-video_url");
  changeVideo(videoUrl);
})
```

**html**

to make more interesting add the videoURL as an data-attribute to the anchor

```
<div id="video">Loading the player ...</div>
<a href="#" class="changeVideo" data-video_url="videoURL2">load video 2</a>
```

that's all you need